# How to remove a field after inserting it?

Tags: react-jsonschema-forms

I am building a custom form, I have successfully been able to add new fields at run time into the form as:

```
Options.schema.properties= {...Options.schema.properties, [key]: {type: "string"} }
Options.uiSchema= {...Options.uiSchema, [key]: { "ui:widget": DefaultInput, classNames: "col-md-4"} }
```

Where `key` is the field id, and `Options` is observable via Mobx

In the form, I am using observable pattern via Mobx to update the `schema.properties`

Something like this:

```
  class StudentsTab extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MyForm schema={Options.schema} uiSchema={Options.uiSchema} widgets={Options.widgets}
      fields={this.customFields} 
        onChange={log("changed")}
        onSubmit={log("submitted")}
        onError={log("errors")}
         />
    )
  }
}
export default observer(StudentsTab);
```

Although a new fields can be added in this way, however, I could not remove them, my attempt was like:

```
   delete Options.schema.properties[key]
   delete Options.uiSchema[key]
```

I can see that the field id is removed, but its not removed from the DOM

Any idea? How would I remove a field after adding it?